# JavaFX wait after setting imageview

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, wait

I need to wait after setting an Imageview, but if I use

```
Thread.sleep(1000)
```

after setting the imageView the whole application sleeps for one second but the imageView will not be set during this period of time.

I would like to know how can I pause the whole application after setting the imageview.

For instance, it's a game of cards (briscola), and after the computer played a card, or I played a card the application should pause to show which cards are on the plate and who won the hand.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
This is what I tried with the tasks, with no success as the images

```
    private void setImages(BriscolaModel model) {
    Set<Map.Entry<Player, BriscolaCard>> entries = model.getPlate().entrySet();


    // set images

    Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
        @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {
            for(Map.Entry<Player, BriscolaCard> entry : entries){
                plate.getImageViews().add(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(entry.getValue().getRelativePath()),200,100,true, false)));
            }
            plate.getCards().getChildren().setAll(plate.getImageViews());
            return 0;
        }
    };

    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.start();

    // clear images 

    Task <Integer> clearTask = new Task<Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer call() throws Exception {
            clearImages();
            return 0;
        }
    };
    Thread clearThread = new Thread(clearTask);
    if(entries.size()==2){
        Platform.runLater(clearTask);
    }else {
        clearThread.start();
    }
}
```

2nd UPDATE:

This seem to work better (i randomly see the images for some milliseconds before being cleared), but how can I set the minimum time to wait before the Platform.runLater() ?

```
private void setImages(BriscolaModel model) {
    Set<Map.Entry<Player, BriscolaCard>> entries = model.getPlate().entrySet();

    for (Map.Entry<Player, BriscolaCard> entry : entries) {
        plate.getImageViews().add(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(entry.getValue().getRelativePath()), 200, 100, true, false)));
    }
    plate.getCards().getChildren().setAll(plate.getImageViews());

    Task<Void> waitTask = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            clearImages();
            return null;
        }
    };

    if(entries.size() == 2){
        Platform.runLater(waitTask);
    }

}
```

Comment: you have to make use of tasks in your application

Comment: Use a task for setting the images or for waiting ?

Comment: for setting the image and then use platform.runlater so that your application UI dosen't freeze

Comment: But I want to wait after the images are set, not before.

Comment: then do the opposite normally run the application set the images and then wait in a task or run in platform.runlater as it will help the UI for not Frezzing

Comment: I updated the question with the code  with tasks. Now it simply doesn't show anything (no cards in the plate).

Comment: why are you adding images inside the task , you have to wait for something i guess after the image is set right ?

Comment: After setting the images i have just to pause the game 2 seconds, and the clear the images (plate) and continue with the game.

Comment: so inside the task you should update the code for deleting all the tiles i:e first getting all and then setting it to null

Comment: Don't use tasks and background threads for this. Just use a `PauseTransition` or a `Timeline`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, thanks to Rahul Singh for the suggestions!

```
private void setImages(BriscolaModel model) {
    Set<Map.Entry<Player, BriscolaCard>> entries = model.getPlate().entrySet();
    plate.getImageViews().clear();

    for (Map.Entry<Player, BriscolaCard> entry : entries) {
        plate.getImageViews().add(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(entry.getValue().getRelativePath()), 200, 100, true, false)));
    }
    plate.getCards().getChildren().setAll(plate.getImageViews());

    Task<Void> waitTask = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
                    Duration.millis(2000),
                    ae -> clearImages()));
            timeline.play();
            return null;
        }
    };

    if(entries.size() == 2){
        Platform.runLater(waitTask);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're using a `Timeline`, there is no need for a `Task`. Just put the code that is in the `call()` method in the `if (entries==2)` block.